# How to copy a big array to memory and use it in OpenCL kernel?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencl, opencl-c++

I have an array of uint8_t. The size of the array is about 2.000.000. I need to do some calculations on these values, but after I call the kernel and copy the modified values back, it returns only zeros.

I'm creating the array, the "row" and "columns" are int.

```
uint8_t arrayIn[rows * columns];
uint8_t arrayOut[rows * columns];
```

I'm creating the cl_mem objects and copy the array data into.

```
arrayInMem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, rows * columns * sizeof(uint8_t), NULL, &err);
arrayOutMem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, rows * columns * sizeof(uint8_t), NULL, &err);
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(img_cmd_queue, arrayInMem, CL_TRUE, 0, rows * columns * sizeof(uint8_t), arrayIn, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Setting the kernel arg like this.

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&arrayInMem);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&arrayOutMem);
```

Reading back to the host the modified array.

```
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(img_cmd_queue, arrayOutMem, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(uint8_t), arrayOut, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The kernel signature look like this:

```
__kernel void calculate(__global uchar * arrayInKernel, __global uchar * arrayOutKernel){
//do some calculation like this eg. 
//int gid = get_global_id(0);
//arrayOutKernel[gid] = 2 * arrayInKernel[gid];
}
```

Could somebody help, what am I missing out?

Comment: What is the value of err after ```err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(img_cmd_queue, arrayInMem, CL_TRUE, 0, rows * columns * sizeof(uint8_t), arrayIn, 0, NULL, NULL);``` ?

Comment: It gives back CL_SUCCESS.

Comment: When calling clEnqueueReadBuffer() You have source and destination in the wrong order.  You want to read from arrayOut (parameter 2: buffer) into arrayOutMem (parameter 6: ptr).

Comment: Yes, because in the kernel I save the modified values there and I want read it back from there. But I understand what you want. The variable names were a bit confusing so I edited them to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Renaming will not change this:  the order of the parameters to clEnqueueReadBuffer is still _buffer_ -> _ptr_, in order of appearance input -> output.  And  your input is the buffer modified by calculate() and your output must be the video buffer you allocated with  clCreateBuffer().

Comment: So the correct method invoke is:
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(img_cmd_queue, arrayOut, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(uint8_t), arrayOutMem, 0, NULL, NULL); ?

Comment: you can increase stack size in compiler/linker options

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, assuming `MEM_SIZE = rows * columns`. The argument order in `clEnqueueReadBuffer` also is correct.

I could imagine that you forgot to call `clFinish(img_cmd_queue);` after `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and `clEnqueueReadBuffer` and before you check the results in `arrayOut`. All these commands end up in a queue and without `clFinish` the queue may be executed after you checked results.